# Remove URL part with IIS Rewrite Rule

Tags: regex, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I need to remove a dynamic part of a URL and I want to use IIS URL Rewrite module for that.

Old URL: http://website.something.com/dadb754e-db91-4a54-a160-a9ad17713048/smoothstream/tk__HbR9-gDC6p9x63Q5sie/dadb754e-db91-4a54-a160-a9ad17713048.ism/manifest

New URL: http://website.something.com/dadb754e-db91-4a54-a160-a9ad17713048/smoothstream/dadb754e-db91-4a54-a160-a9ad17713048.ism/manifest

The part tk__HbR9-gDC6p9x63Q5sie/ is dynamically but the first 3 characters are always the same.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex: `(tk_[\w\-]*\/)` which will give you the dynamic part and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: thanks, but do I need to create an out- or an inbound rule?

and would the rule look like

Comment: I think you need to create an inbound rule (because you need to modify the actual URL of your requests). Outbound rules are used to modify the content of HTTP responses. Read more [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/url-rewriting-with-iiss-url-rewrite-module/). Once you get to the `Pattern` field, just paste in the regex above. Hope it helps.